# AngularJs - Get a string from compiled HTML/Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to get a string that i can edit later (with Textangular or saved it in DB) from a template coming from server (in DB).

```
    TemplateMailService.get($scope.type, function (data, status) {


            $scope.template = data.template;
            // data.template.content = '<p>Hi <span ng-if="client.email == 'email@email.com'">{{email}}</span>!</p>'
            $timeout(function () {

                data.template.content = $compile(data.template.content)($scope);

                $log.debug('$scope.mail.content : ', $scope.mail.content);
                $log.debug('data.template.content : ', angular.element(data.template.content));
                // is compiled correctly. I can see the ng-if apply and the {{variable}} compiled
                var string = '';
                string += data.template.content[0].innerHTML;

                console.log(string);
                // => ng-if not apply and {{variable}} not compiled...

                $scope.mail.content = string;
            }, 0);

    })
```

I want to be able to save the compiled template (with all the ng-xx and {{ variables}} applied in a string to edit it in textangular.

I know i should be doing this with a directive but i dont get how i can return the compiled template in a string.

What i'm missing here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## `$parse`

`$parse` can be used to evaluate single expressions like any `{{variable}}` you have in your `data.template.content[0].innerHTML;` string.

## `$interpolate`

I think this is the solution to getting your compiled string, because `$interpolate` knows how to process a string with expressions like `<p ng-if='myObject'>Hello {{myName}}</p>`

Comment: Even if i wrap my compiled template in $sce.trustAsHtml it's still returned uncompiled... and ngSanitize is already added in my project. I dont want to display the string i just want to be able to manipulate it after being compiled.